# Obsolete-Attribute on awaitable's type GetAwaiter method is a breaking change

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, async-await, c#-5.0

I have implemented my own awaitable type by providing the following four instance members:

```
public bool IsCompleted { get; }
public void OnCompleted(Action continuation); 
public AwaitResult GetResult(); 
public object GetAwaiter();
```

Because that was all the compiler was asking me for in order to accept

```
MyAwaitableType obj = new MyAwaitableType();
await obj;
```

I marked all of them with

```
[Obsolete("Do not use in code.", true)]
```

so that whenever any of the members is called from code instead of using await it results in a build error. Using the Obsolete-Attribute in this scenario is not the way it is intended for – yet I don't know any better way (anxious to hear a better solution if there is one), but it worked fine with the C# compiler included in Visual Studio 2012.

I opened the solution unchanged in Visual Studio 2015 and it seems that the C# compiler got a bit pickier because it complains about the obsoleteness of the GetAwaiter method and shows squiggles underneath the `await obj` statement.

Getting rid of the error is easy, however I would love to know why the compilers seems to access the GetAwaiter method now in a regular manner compared to what it did in Visual Studio 2012 (possibly over reflection?). My understanding is that whether a type is awaitable is a pattern-matching-based (the four required members exist or not) and not an interface-implemented-based issue.

Comment: I don't have a direct answer to your question, but one way would be to write an analyzer that handled that.

Comment: The bug was the *previous* behaviour. If you mark something as obsolete it means it shouldn't be used, no matter who calls it. Your previous code depended on a bug and would certainly break at some point. There are other cases as well where the compiler behaves in a saner fashion now